Linear response theory for dry friction at steady state
In this paper, Brownian motion with dry friction has been studied rigorously. The formulae for the propagator and the steady state are given. Since it is not reversible, the steady state should be a non-equilibrium steady state if I am not mistaken.
Would it make sense to study the response of the system to perturbations under steady state for this type of system (discuss mobility, diffusivity)? Maybe it could be used for showing that the fluctuation relation dissipation does not hold.
